# Damage by chown command at /

Tags: permissions, chown, system-recovery

I was careless for just a second and managed to type (being logged as root) on my Ubuntu system:

```
chown foobar /*
chown foobar /*/*
```

What is the possible extent of the damage, and how can I revert it?

Comment: Please note that I didn't change the group - only the owner and NOT recursively, just one level down. So, that's why I still have a slight hope...

Comment: Just do `chown root /*/*`. Should be okay. Then set all the home directories to have correct permissions and group

Comment: @123 I don't think everything under `/` is owned by root though.

Comment: @Zacharee1 It is on mine. Directly under `/` at least.

Comment: Everything in `/` is, but certainly not `/*/*`.

Comment: @123 really? Even `/home/123`? That's surprising to say the least. Please don't suggest such sweeping commands without testing them.

Comment: @terdon I mentioned home to set those right.

Comment: @123 ah, yes, so you did. That would still not fix it for things like `/var/www` or other directories owned by special users though.

Comment: @Foufoutos what type of machine is this? Is it personal or production? Also, what is the OS?

Comment: Apart from `/home`, `/tmp` and `/run` will likely contain files owned by others than root, but those can be just emptied with a reboot. Plus possibly service-owned directories inside `/var` (though depending on system they might still be owned by root)

Comment: Could make a list of 3rd level permissions for 2 level directories using something like `find / -maxdepth 3 -mindepth 3 ! -regex "/proc.*" | xargs -I{} stat -c "%n %U.%G" {} | awk '{sub(/[^\/]*$/,"",$1);a[$1]=$2}END{for(i in a)if(a[i]!~/root.root/)` to give you an idea of what permissions 2nd level folders have.

Comment: @Zacharee1 That list everything, I tried to condense it a bit to just what you would need to chown.

Comment: @123 that seems overly complex. Why not just `find / -maxdepth 2 -ls | awk '$5!="root" && $6!="root" && $NF!~/^\/proc/ && $NF!~/^\/tmp/'`? Although, that assumes GNU `find` and will break on filenames containing newlines. Then again, anyone who has file names with newlines two levels down from `/` deserves what they get.

Comment: @terdon Because that doesn't get the third level, so everything will owned by root/foobar/whatever you set them to accidently ? My idea was to check what was in the directories that haven't been changed to get an idea of who should own the upper directory,

Comment: @123 but the chown only covered second level. `/*/*` is only everything under everything under `/` (not a typo), not everything under everything under everything under `/`.

Comment: @Zacharee1 Yes so the third level is untouched and has proper permissions and can give you an idea of what the parent directory should be. Also there was supposed to be `print i,a[i]}'` at the end of my previous command that seems to not be there...

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. But I don't know if that would really give a good indication. Subdirectories don't always share permissions.

Comment: @Zacharee1 Unfortunately is production machine, at work. Runs 14.04 LTS. I ended up with a machine not wanting to log me in as ROOT, and falling into login loop. Eventually, I saved home folder and created a new user, but root access is still problematic, I use `sudo su` in order to gain admin access

Comment: @Foufoutos is it a plausible strategy to backup user folders and data and reinstall? `/home/username` needs to be owned by `username`, so if you changed it to `zw`, you should fix that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like there isn't really much that needs fixing, at least on a **fresh install of Ubuntu 15.10**. Of course, if you've installed stuff, you will have files and directories that I don't. However, I believe this output will show the proper permissions to keep Ubuntu running. Some programs may be broken because of the command you ran, but Ubuntu will at least run, and you can go about reinstalling applications from there.

If something doesn't work, try setting the owner to the group. It might not have been the same originally, but it's worth a shot if the app isn't working.

By running `shopt -s extglob; find /!(proc|tmp|dev|run|root|lost+found) -maxdepth 1 -ls | awk '$5!="root" || $6!="root"'` (Thanks @terdon), I came up with the following:

```
131226    4 -rw-r-----   1 root     shadow        824 Jun 21 14:34 /etc/gshadow
131284    4 -rw-r-----   1 root     shadow       1212 Jun 21 14:34 /etc/shadow
131095    4 drwxr-s---   2 root     dip          4096 Oct 21  2015 /etc/chatscripts
131103    4 drwxr-xr-x   5 root     lp           4096 Jul 19 07:00 /etc/cups
find: `/mnt/hgfs': Protocol error
1064478    4 drwxr-xr-x  16 zw       zw           4096 Jul 19 07:26 /home/zw
655571   36 -rwxr-sr-x   1 root     shadow      35536 Apr 22  2015 /sbin/unix_chkpwd
655516   36 -rwxr-sr-x   1 root     shadow      35576 Apr 22  2015 /sbin/pam_extrausers_chkpwd
150670    4 drwxrwsrwt   2 root     whoopsie     4096 Oct 21  2015 /var/metrics
150669    4 drwxrwsr-x   2 root     mail         4096 Oct 21  2015 /var/mail
150668    4 drwxrwxr-x  14 root     syslog       4096 Jul 19 07:00 /var/log
150664    4 drwxrwsrwt   2 root     whoopsie     4096 Oct 21  2015 /var/crash
150666    4 drwxrwsr-x   2 root     staff        4096 Oct 19  2015 /var/local
```

- The command excludes `/root` and `/lost+found`, as everything under `/root` and `/lost+found` is owned by `root`. Make sure to set the ownership accordingly.
- The command excludes `/proc`, `/tmp`, `/dev` and `/run` as these directories contain files that are reset upon reboot.
- `/mnt` and `/media` may have had special permissions set on subdirectories. A reboot may fix the ones under `/media`, but I'm not sure about `/mnt`.

There aren't very many directories you need to pay attention to, since most of them are owned by `root`. If you have any extra directories under `/*/*` that I don't have, try setting their owners to `root` or their corresponding groups. For everything that does match, just fix the permissions.

I would reverse the two commands by running what you ran, but replacing `foobar` with `root`. Then you can fix the other permissions afterward.

Comment: What crazy syntax is `/!(proc|tmp|dev|run|root|lost+found)` ? What version of find is this? Nvm it's extglob isn't it!

Comment: It's whatever terdon put together @123. It's just excluding any of those directories before it even does the other filtering.